# GODOT add_to_group with an inheritance variable

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have several nodes under several different parent nodes. Each child node inherets from a base script as they all have the same functions, just different individual variable values. On "_ready", I want each node to add itself to a group named after its parent.

Base.gd:

```
extends Area2D

export var _parent: String

func _ready() -> void:
     add_to_group(_parent)
```

Node1.gd

```
extends "res://Base.gd"

func _ready() -> void:
     _parent = "MyParentNode"
```

This seems like it should add Node1 to the group "MyParentNode". I also get this debug error:

add_to_group: Condition "!p_identifier.operator String().length()" is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Godot will call `_ready` on the base class first, recursively. I go into detail on how Godot calls `_ready` in [my answer to How to know if an overriden method calls its super method or not?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/192257/10408)

Thus, Godot will call this:

```
func _ready() -> void:
     add_to_group(_parent)
```

And then this:

```
func _ready() -> void:
     _parent = "MyParentNode"
```

As a result, `_parent` was not set when calling `add_to_group`.

---

Now, given that you want to set a variable, I suggest using `setget`:

```
extends Area2D

export var _parent:String setget ser_parent

func set_parent(new_value:String) -> void:
    if _parent == new_value:
        return

    if is_in_group(_parent):
        remove_from_group(_parent)

    add_to_group(new_value)
    _parent = new_value
```

That way, every time the derived class sets `_parent`, it will be adding and removing the node from groups accordingly.

---

By the way, and just in case, if you only plan to use this for `is_in_group`, then you don't need groups at all. Instead of checking `if node.is_in_group(something)` you can just check `if node._parent == something`.

Furthermore, if this is predicated on the parent node, you can check the parent node with `get_parent()`: `if node.get_parent() == something` or `if node.get_parent().name == something`. *And I remind you about `get_children`.*